# NameError: name 'A' is not defined

Tags: python

QUESTION:
Write a program that takes a position on a chess board as a column col and row value row and checks whether or not the position is valid. Remember that the column in a chess board is a letter ranging from A to H (inclusive) and the row is a number between 1 and 8 (inclusive). A3 or E7 are valid inputs but a1 or L5 are not. If both coordinates are valid, such as E2, the programs prints 'The piece is moved to E2.', otherwise it prints 'The position is not valid.'.

MY ANSWER:

```
a=raw_input("you move to:")
col = [A, B, C, D, E, F, G]
row = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
if (a in col) and (a in row):
 print 'The piece is moved to '%s%d   %input
else:
 print 'The position is not valid.'
```

ERROR (after plugging in a value like D5)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<web session>", line 2, in <module>
NameError: name 'A' is not defined
```

REQUEST:

Can you direct my on how to fix my program?

CONTEXT:

The purpose of this task is to set me up to answer the following QUESTION:

So far, your program used two separate inputs: a column and a row value. Can you modify your previous program (chess problem, version 3) to accept the position on the chess board as a single input. In other words, assume that there is a variable position which stores both the column and the row value of a chess board such as B5. When both the coordinates in the input are valid, for example, c4, the program prints the message The piece is moved to c4.. If the first coordinate is out of range, print The first coordinate is not in the range a-h or A-H!, if the second coordinate is out range, print The second coordinate is not in the range 1 to 8!.

CLOSE:

Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is here:

```
col = [A, B, C, D, E, F, G]
```

Your list is supposed to contain strings, so you need to quote each letter just like how you quoted the strings in your `print` statements. Unquoted, they're being treated as identifiers (for variables, classes, functions, etc) and that's how you end up with your error.

Additionally, as mentioned in [Voooza's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7311317/nameerror-name-a-is-not-defined/7311367#7311367), you need to slice/index the input string (`a[0]` gets the first character which is the letter, and `a[1]` gets the second character which is the number). Either quote all the numbers in `row` or cast `a[1]` into an int by doing `int(a[1])` for the comparison to work.

Finally, since your raw input variable is called `a`, you need to format your first `print` statement using `a` and not `input`.

Comment: @agf: Well, yeah... I'll add to my answer in a moment.

Answer (score 2):

```
col = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G']
```

Otherwise it looks for variables A, B, C... and can't find them

Comment: I like this answer better because the code block gives a solution rather than pointing out the problem.  @BoltClock is correct, but it takes more thought to figure it out from his solution.

Comment: @Carl F.: It was a homework question so I didn't really want to provide the solution up front. Either way...

Comment: That's a good point.  There ought to be a different style of answer for homework.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to quote each of 'A', 'B', etc, so that they are parsed as strings, rather than identifiers.

Answer (score 0):

you need to put chars in quotes

```
col = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G']
```

and you need to use slices

```
if (a[0] in col) and (a[1] in row):
 print 'The piece is moved to '%s%d   %input
else:
 print 'The position is not valid.'
```

finaly you need to cast input to number or qoute numbers in row as well

Comment: +1, but you missed the fact that you need to include `H` and `8`.

Answer (score -1):

Complete program must looks like

```
col = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G']
row = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
pos=raw_input("you move to:")
try:
    x=pos[0] # A1 > A
    y=pos[1] # A1 > 1
    if (x in col) and (int(y) in row):
       print 'The piece is moved to %s' % pos
except:
   print 'The position is not valid.'
```

Comment: This doesn't count any two letter or greater entry, where the second is a number, as invalid. `!593utewjvkns.` would print no message but not be found invalid.

Comment: -1 since I don't think the OP is going to learn from this at all, it's too far from what he came up with and doesn't give any explanation what is wrong with what he did